# Alternative to 4/3 camera without compromising quality

Tags: panasonic, four-thirds

I have a **Panasonic DMC L1** (the first 4/3 camera) with Leica zoom lens and an Olympus fixed focal length lens.

The Leica lens has developed a problem and the insurance can't repair it. They are going to offer me an alternative ...likely to be a camera within £700.

I suspect they will offer me the Lumix G series. I quite liked the micro 4/3 cameras as they are smaller. However, I suspect the picture quality, especially at night without the excellent bounce flash of the L1, would be not as good. I also liked the controls on the L1.

Should I go for a micro 4/3 or should I go for the 4/3 like G series?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you mean when you say you don't want to compromise quality? What quality do you mean, exactly, and do you mean compromised vs. your six-year-old camera or 4/3rds vs. micro 4/3rds?

Comment: I am sorry..I was quite vague.

Comment: What I meant to say was that the quality of my old camera is excellent. Would the Micro 4/3 quality be a lot different(inferior)? I know the GX1 and EP3 are good, but can they match the quality of the L1? If not, should I go for an SLR by Nikon or Fuji?

Comment: The technical image quality of the modern 4/3rds and micro 4/3rds sensors is generally regarded as much better than that from early-generation 4/3rds — even at the entry-level, and particularly at higher ISOs. I would be more concerned with features and handling.

Comment: If the lens is faulty, why don't you look into getting a new 4/3 lens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The image quality of a 4/3 and Micro Four-Thirds camera is exactly the same** since the sensors are the same size. Therefore you can expect better image quality from newer 3/4 or Micro 4/3 cameras due to technological improvements.

It is normal that there will be differences when changing models and even though what you are getting will be some kind of *upgrade*, there will be some things you will like less.

One **improvement over previous generations is that newer cameras focus much faster**. So, at this point, without knowing much about your photography style, all I can say is that you choose the right model considering your needs. If you like using direct controls than you should look at advanced models and if you are more comfortable using the camera at eye-level, so you should look at the models with a built EVF. Finally you can always get a 4/3 DSLR from like the [Olympus E-5](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/olympus/e5/review).